# Most convenient way to pass a React Native app to a friend

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I'm going to create a React Native application that will be used by a very limited number of people.

During development I can see the changes right on my phone in real time, but what if I want to transfer the app to another person's phone? Do I need to generate an apk for every change, send it as a file to the person and have them download it and install it, is there a faster way?

I tried to find the answer online, but I only find information about uploading app to the app stores

Comment: This may get closed as it will vary based on opinion, but you might want to look into Expo Go.